# how to add nameserver in resolv.conf

Tags: linux, nameservers

I researched about how to add a name server in the file `resolv.conf`, I found this command on [this site](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/topic/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds4/namerslv.htm):

```
namerslv -a -i ip address
```

I'm also confused with the example in that site, this one:

```
namerslv -a { -i IPAddress | -D DomainName| -S SearchList}
```

so which one I should use if I want to add just the name server?

```
-i
-D or
-S (I have doubts about this)
```

When I try to use it, it's not supported on my Linux.

Also, why is it important to list at least two name servers in the file `resolv.conf`?

Comment: Link which you have posted relates to AIX. AIX is not a Linux and many commands do differ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`vim /etc/resolv.conf`

Edit file - usually you would have:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

possibly:

```
domain local.example.com
```

or:

```
search local.example.com
```

This will help you with searches like:

`host hostname`

rather then

`host fqdn`

Adding more than one DNS entry is important from the redundancy point of view - if one fails you can still resolve names.

Comment: so there's no command line command for that?

Comment: you can always do `echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf` if you want to add a nameserver.

Comment: DHCP will replace that file periodically

Comment: editing the resolv.conf manually is not a permanent solution to this problem

Comment: What would be a permanent solution for this?

Comment: If it's not allowing you to edit your resolv.conf file it may be set to immutable which you can fix using  chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: I advise you to put your own configuration file into /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/ instead of modifying /etc/resolv.conf which might be overwritten by NetworkManager.

Answer (score -1):

why cant you edit and modify it directly

nameserver 
search company.com

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @HinataHyuga why it does not answer? answer from Chris is also same by with elaborated procedure...

Comment: If it's not allowing you to edit your resolv.conf file it may be set to immutable which you can fix using  chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf